# Optional and required contains in tuples and list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
roles <class 'tuple'>: ('admin', 'root', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
user_roles <class 'tuple'>: ('admin', 'root', 'c')
```

I want to check these two situations.

user_roles must have both admin and root.

and

user_roles must have any of a, b, c

How can I do that in python?

Comment: Please paste whatever code you have tried for achieving this so we can provide better help

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not a program writing site, it is a site for fixing problems in code. Have a go, and come back when you have a code you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

based on my understanding of your question, below should work. please post more details /sample will discuss

roles =('admin', 'root', ['a', 'b', 'c'])

user_roles=('admin', 'root', 'c')

def check(roles):

```
if ('admin' in roles) and ('root' in roles):

    if isinstance(roles[2],str):

        if  'a' == roles[2] or 'b' == roles[2] or 'c' == roles[2]:

            print('these satisfy both conditions')

    elif isinstance(roles[2],list):

        if 'a' in roles[2] or 'b' in roles[2] or 'c' in roles[2]:

            print('these satisfy both conditions')
```

check(roles)

check(user_roles)